# Windows 10 - can I have 2 shortcut to Chrome on the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Can I have 2 shortcuts to Chrome on the taskbar? I want to have two shortcuts to open Chrome on my desktop - one with and another without the in-cognito mode startup flag (with different color icons).

How do I get both icons on the taskbar? I've sent one to the taskbar by right clicking it but it won't let me do that with the 2nd one. I've also tried putting the icon in the TaskBar folder and signing in and out but that didn't work. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following workaround:

1. Pin the first link (without special parameters) normally
2. Create a shortcut on your Desktop via right click --> new --> shortcut
3. Choose some random target for the new shortcut like notepad.exe
4. Right click the newly created shortcut and choose properties. Change the icon to the symbol you want (important: this has to be done before pinning)
5. Drag this new shortcut to the task bar thus pinning it.
6. Hold down shift while right clicking the now pinned symbol, choose properties
7. Change the target path to the one you want including parameters
8. Delete the shortcut on the desktop.

Comment: This worked great although I did need to change the folder it was starting in as well. Cheers. Brill!

Comment: Sorry spoke too soon. when I close the window of the 2nd icon down the icon disappears.

Comment: the icon is pinned and then you start the process and close it and the icon gets unpinned again?

Comment: it seems chrome is a bit special in this case and does not really work with this hack. I tried it with notepad.exe and everything was fine but chrome indeed is more tricky.. well there are other workarounds for this so I'll post the next best one

Answer (score 0):

As chrome does not seem to like being fooled into a second copy here is another possible workaround:

1. Create a folder somewhere where it does not bother you, and put in both links
2. Right click the taskbar choose "Toolbars" -> "New Toolbar" and browse to your folder
3. Right click taskbar and make sure "lock taskbar" is not checked (uncheck if it is)
4. Use mouse to drag your toolbar to the left
5. Right click your toolbar (not one of the icons, the double pipe to the left of the toolbar works fine) and choose "view" -> "large icons" and disable "show title" and "show text"
6. adjust the toolbar size so that it is a little big bigger than it has to be because if you enable "lock taskbar" again it will shrink a bit
7. lock taskbar again

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem using directory junctions, one for each additional profile for which you want an icon in the taskbar.

```
mklink /j Application2 "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
```

This command line creates a directory junction called "Application2" at the same level as the original directory that contains the executable chrome.exe.

Then you have to change icon, target and directory to start, in the shortcut.